# How to fit screen as per device/screen resolution?

Tags: javascript, css, extjs4, screen, extjs4.1

I have done application using Extjs4.1 working very nicely. client they need screen like once they visit application url in different device except phone. All screens should be fit as per device without any horizontal/vertical scroll bar. **I have included a line of code in the index.html file within head, meta tag as below. so now application is fitting in ipad without any scroll bar.** In my desktop monitor also screen is fitting nicely, but same application url if i browse in laptop horizontal/vertical scroll bar coming. How to fit all screens in laptop device like ipad/desktop monitor?. I am not using flex, because if it small device it will fit, but problem all component will be merge one above the other(overlap) while minimizing/maximizing also has the problem. **Can any body tell me how to resolve this issue?** Great appropriated. Thank you

**Code is Here:**

```
<head>      
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1024">    
</head>
```

Comment: Devices have different aspect ratio. Besides, iPad's width is 1024, not 1124

Comment: i have updated, can u give me solution for laptop device?

Comment: Try this <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no; width=device-width; height=device-height; initial-scale=1.0;">

Comment: I have applied but getting error: Viewport argument value "no;" for key "user-scalable" not recognized. Content ignored.

Comment: k remove that use user-scalable=no and set only the width and height.

Comment: removed and tested. no change same as old screen is scrolling. In console i am getting these warnings.

Comment: Viewport argument value "1441;" for key "width" was truncated to its numeric prefix. Note that ';' is not a separator in viewport values. The list should be comma-separated. index.html:7
Viewport argument value "710;" for key "height" was truncated to its numeric prefix. Note that ';' is not a separator in viewport values. The list should be comma-separated.Viewport argument value "1.0;" for key "initial-scale" was truncated to its numeric prefix. Note that ';' is not a separator in viewport values. The list should be comma-separated.

Comment: I have removed warnings. I have gievn like this, now no warnings  <meta name="viewport" content="width=1441, height=710, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: but behavior is same in laptop no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In extjs not able to differentiate laptop and desktop device. I have gone different way. but this not correct way. we can achive as per requirement. In view globally calculating height of the screen. if screen resolution is 1600X900 (Desktop) window.ineerHeight will be come more than 700. if screen resolution is less  than 1600x900 window.innerHeight will be less than 700. So here calculating dynamic value assigning to component. it is working very nicely for me. Cheers

**Here is my code:**

```
if(window.innerHeight>700){ 
    var paddingValue = 10; 
    var imgHeight = window.innerHeight/4.1; //Desktop
}
else{
   var paddingValue = window.innerHeight/35;
   var imgHeight = window.innerHeight/5.7;  //Laptop 
}
```